# Passing a string from C# to a c++ .dll is scrambling the data

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a c++ dll, with this code:

```
extern "C"
{
    const char *SaveDate;

    __declspec(dllexport) void SetDate(const char *date)
    {
        SaveDate = date;

        std::cout << "date: " << SaveDate  << std::endl;

    }
}
```

When i print the value inside that function, it prints

```
'date: 20160215'
```

But when I grab the 'SaveDate' variable from another function, and print it, it prints

```
'104'
```

My C# is:

```
[DllImport("XmlRecord.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SetSlate(string date);


public bool SetupRec()
{
    string Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    SetSlate(Date);
}
```

Why is this value being scrambled in the c++ dll?

Thank you.

Comment: Because the GC already collected the memory.  You need to pin it.

Comment: @SLaks actually that's the P/Invoke marshaler's memory, you can't pin that, it's already an unmovable copy of the data...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use P/Invoke, any argument passed to your C function will be valid **for the duration of the call**.

If you want to reuse the input string, you need to copy it. The one you got as argument will be freed after the call (and you don't even know *when*). Just save it to a `std::string` instead of holding a `const char *`.

If you absolutely want to avoid copying the data, there are mechanisms you could leverage, but you'll have to take the appropriate precautions on the C# side, as the GC is allowed to move objects in memory at any time.
This involves long-term object pinning (with the `GCHandle` class), which is a hindrance to the GC, so it's best avoided. Short-term pinning (with the `fixed` statement) is doable if you can limit the data validity to a single stack frame. You'll then have to pass your data as an `IntPtr` to the C function, to bypass the .NET marshaling.

Comment: Thanks! So I should write a copy function that creates a 'local' copy? If i initialize std::string SaveDate; I cannot use SaveDate = date;

Comment: @Ben you could use `SaveDate.assign(date);` for this purpose, although `operator=` is overloaded for `const char*` so `SaveDate = date;` should work too.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your help!